# Finalizar todas as threads filhas de uma activity

Tags: java, android

Em minha activity eu instâncio alguns controles que buscam dados do servidor de maneira assíncrona.

A instância do controle é a seguinte:

```
new controle().executar(new InterfaceRetorno(){...});
```

Mas o que acontece é o seguinte, caso o usuário aperte o botão de voltar eu destruo a activity com o método finish(). E é aí que está o problema, pois se a interface não tiver atualizado o TextView ainda, quando ela retornar algo e tentar atualizar, vai dar um null exeption

Como faço pra finalizar todas as ações que estão ocorrendo que são filha dessa activity?

Comment: Coloque o código de uma dessas Threads.

Answer (score 0):

use o método onDestroy na activity para efetuar as finalizações dos processos...embora eu recomende usar uma classe chamada AsyncTask para realizar esses processos.

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // cancelar a requisição
    }
```